# Right control is bound, but Left control is unbound

Tags: autohotkey

In my keyboard, the letter c and q is broken. My intention is to replace it with right ctrl+S and right ctrl+K, with the intention to make left ctrl works normally. It works to type just c and q, but suddenly left ctrl+s means s and left ctrl+k means k, instead of a normal ctrl+s. I also intend to make it work when both ctrl is pressed, so left ctrl+right ctrl+s is ctrl+c, which is used to copy a text.

Basically:

- Left ctrl = normal
- right ctrl = type the broken letter
- both key needs to compose, so I can type left ctrl + right ctrl + s

My current code is:

```
>^s::send c
>^k::send q
```

Note that both ctrl works normally for other letters. How to fix that?

Also, if this is still the same question, it also doesn't work with capslock and shift. If the answer also fixes that, I will appreciate that.

Comment: Are you sure about your choice? (CTRL + S) is a very common combination.

Comment: Btw script works for me: `#SingleInstance 
#persistent
SetKeyDelay, -1
^k::
 Send q
Return` There might be an issue in your remaining part?

Comment: @MuzafferGalata That's why I want to keep the left ctrl works as normal.

Comment: Did you try my script above? It has been worked for me.

Comment: @MuzafferGalata Nope, probably put it on pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/2e1a0702

Comment: @MuzafferGalata nope even worse. Now, left ctrl acts like right ctrl. If I add > before ^, the problem is the same as my own problem. It's still doesn't work with shift and capslock either.

Comment: Wait, I found out that my left ctrl doesn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221232/discussion-between-muzaffer-galata-and-xwtek).

Comment: Sounds like time for a new keyboard... 